# gatling group actions in foreach into parallel chunks

Tags: gatling

I have a gatling scenario where I retrieve 1000 documents from a database via a RESTful API.

I then modify the documents and send update requests for each.

This is how I'm currently doing it:

```
...
val scrollQueries = scenario("Enrichment Topologies").exec(ScrollQueryInitiator.query, repeat(numberOfPagesToScrollThrough, "scrollQueryCounter"){
    exec(ScrollQuery.query, pause(10 seconds).foreach("${hitsJson}", "hit"){ exec(HitProcessor.query) })
})
...
```

Here are the main features of interest:

1. `ScrollQuery.query` fetches the 1000 results and saves them into `hitsJson` in the session.
2. It then pauses for 10 seconds to simulate longer-term processing.
3. The 1000 results are iterated over and for each item a `HitProcessor` is run which sends the update request

In reality, the foreach loop ensures that each request is sent one after the other.

## Question

What I really want is to work through the 1000 results in groups of 10, sending update requests in parallel 10 at a time.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the fetch part to before [hook](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.3/general/simulation_structure.html).

Now that you have the data you can start 10 threads

```
setUp(  scn.inject(atOnceUsers(10)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need the requests that get the data to be part of the scenario.